# How can I clean up this aggregated query?

Tags: mysql, group-by, aggregate-functions

I wrote a query to pull some data for my organization. I want to pull all the fields that I have listed after "select" but I feel there must be a cleaner way to write the "Group By" Statement at the end. It seems like it would be cumbersome to have to write every column out under the group by clause.

This is a shortened version of the query for illustrative purposes. This will be expanded. With the current query, I would add about 10 fields to the "group by" clause

```
select
membr as AccountID,
seqnm as SequenceName,
mtype as AccountType, 
SUM(PAYAM) as PaidAmt
from oombrmst join OOPayHST on membr = hmembr
GROUP BY Membr, seqnm, mtype
```

I haven't tried much to be honest, I am still (clearly) a beginner

Comment: My question to you is: why would you want to `GROUP BY` every field in your query?  it serves no purpose (unless I am missing something) - It's OK to group by one or two columns (to organize the results, perhaps) but I see no need to group by ALL 10.

Comment: There is no shortcut to this,'If the ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY SQL mode is enabled (which it is by default), MySQL rejects queries for which the select list, HAVING condition, or ORDER BY list refer to nonaggregated columns that are neither named in the GROUP BY clause nor are functionally dependent on them.' - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html - this answers the question , but not the question behind the question possibly

Comment: @blurfus well....exactly. My query fails when I don't do a group by in every field. The error message I get is "Column 'oombrmst.MEMBR' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause." Is there a way to bypass this error message without grouping by all the columns?